# Spark Job Completes but shows Incomplete Tasks : Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a Spark Job using spark-submit.
In this i am Iterating 3-4 queries which will run sequentially.

While the Entire jobs gets Completed Successfully WHY it still shows Active Jobs and Pending Tasks. As we can see in Job ID : 0 , None of the stages are complete. Also under Tasks.

What can be the reason for this ?? Why this happens

[image: Incomplete Job Progress]

Comment: Sad to see no answer almost a year after your post.  I'm seeing the exact same thing and confused as to what's happening.  Trying to give this a bump and see if anyone (or maybe you figured it out) has any insight they could offer here...?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126052/what-is-active-jobs-in-spark-history-server-spark-ui-jobs-section

Comment: Please check this out